# Calculate interest

Tags: investment, present-value

I'm kinda stuck with the following problem.

I am given the terms in Month, a net-value, a residual value, and a monthly rate. Now my job is to calculate the interest. Usually I am giving the interest and calculate anything else using the following formula:

[image]

where $n$ is the terms in month, $R$ is the monthly rate, $L$ is the net-Value, $RW$ is the residual value after $n$ months. Finally $q = (1+i)$, where $i$ is the interest.

Any idea how to solve this for $q$, i.e. the interest?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't derive a formula from this equation to calculate $q$ (or $i$) directly for all values of $n$ given the other variables.

However, you can use the RATE() function in Excel (or a similar function in another electronic spreadsheet program) to find $i$. You can also set up a payment schedule similar to [the loan amortization table shown here](https://openoregon.pressbooks.pub/beginningexcel/chapter/2-3-functions-for-personal-finance/) in Excel for a given initial value, monthly payment, residual value, and period and use [the Solver add-in](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/define-and-solve-a-problem-by-using-solver-5d1a388f-079d-43ac-a7eb-f63e45925040#OfficeVersion=Windows) or go by trial-and-error to find $i$. See [this online lease calculator](https://www.efunda.com/formulae/finance/lease_calculator.cfm) if you would like to double-check your calculations.

Comment: Yeah ok, I thought of this already then I need to use a rather numerical apporach to find the solution thanks!